# How to set i/p values inactive while other i/p is active in SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm new in SSRS reporting. I've a doubt on setting parameters.
I need to create  a SSRS report with 3 i/p values a,b &c. The condition is if a & b has values then C should not be active..How to apply this ?
I could not find any option like this in parameters. 
Somebody please help..

Regards,
Julie

Answer (score 0):

I think SSRS doesn't have any native feature like this.

I would provide c with available values from a dataset.  If a & b have values then the dataset for c would return 1 row e.g. "All".  I would set the Default Values for c to the same dataset, so it will work without user intervention.

Then in the main datasets I would code for the "All" value being passed as parameter c.